# How to validate uniqueness for siblings' name attribute?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, ancestry

I have `Category` model with tree structure via `ancestry` gem. 
I'd like siblings to have unique names, for example:

```
Books:
  Science
  science (not valid)
```

But

```
Books:
  Science
  Children:
    Science (valid)
```

How can I setup this validation?

Comment: Children of one object can not have same name, but children from other objects can? No matter they are on same level?

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Rails validate uniqueness](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#uniqueness) with scope defined.

For example let's say you have a column called `parent_id` then your validation would look like

`validates :name, uniqueness: { scope: :parent_id }`

Answer (score 0):

You can write your own validator using ActiveRecord `validate` to check the childrens of the parent record like:

```
class Category < ApplicationRecord
  has_ancestry
  validate :children_name_is_unique

  def children_name_is_unique
    return unless parent.try(:has_children?)
    if Category.where(id: parent.child_ids, name: name).exists?
      errors.add(:name, 'Duplicate children name')
    end
  end
end
```